# ExternalContext#dispatch() showing ENV_UNSUPPORTED - "This operation is not supported in this version of Java. Java EE 5 required"

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, dispatch

**Background -**
I am currently working on a JSF migration project. The JSF application is written long back in JSF 1.2 and now we are required to migrate it to JSF 2.2/2.3.

**Issue -**
The application is using `externalContext.dispatch()` method to forward it to launch page. We have moved to latest JSF jars and done the necessary java changes. Now when we are trying to launch the home page, the application launch is going into infinite loop. When I run the application in DEBUG mode, I can see the message as :

> ENV_UNSUPPORTED for externalContext.dispatch() = "This operation is not supported in this version of java. Java EE 5 required".

I am out of ideas now how to solve this.

Since I am working in a secured environment, I can not paste any code or logs. Apologies for it!

Comment: What Java JDK version are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.7.

Comment: Is your JSF request an Ajax request when executing `dispatch()`?

Comment: No Buhake. It is not an Ajax request. When I am entering my application localhost url, the execution is happening properly till dispatch. After this, it is going into infinite loop. Somehow, the JSF life cycle is getting corrupted, it seems. Moreover, After further analysis, I can see that wherever ExternalContext has been used, the ENV_UNSUPPORTED warning is present. I am not able to find any documentation where it shows that ExternalContext is now unsupported.

Comment: Have you included JSF apis and/or JSF implementation jars in your deployment? ie. do they appear in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file? Remove them if you have.

Comment: Yeah @SteveC. I have included javax.faces-2.2.8 jar in my project. The reason behind it is I am using IBM RSA 8.5 whose default JSF implementation is myFaces while the project is in Sun RI JSF (now oracle mojarra). As [per tutorial on IBM developer site] (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/devTips/entry/Using_a_Custom_JSF_implementation_with_WebSphere_Liberty_Profile?lang=en), we need to add JSF libraries for oracle mojarra. I'll try removing the library and deploy again.